# how to recover deep freeze password

Tags: deep-freeze, passwords, password-recovery

Please help, I've lost my deep freeze password. What do I do? I need to disable it but I forgot the password. Is there any software that can be used to uninstall it even if its enabled.

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/147180/uninstall-deep-freeze-manually-using-registry

Comment: For Faronics' s sake, one should hope that you can't recover the password. contact their support: http://www.faronics.com/en/Support.aspx

Comment: For people who don't know, DeepFreeze is a program that restores the hard drive and registry to an image every restart.

Comment: @Hello71 it does not restore to an image on each reboot. It prevents any changes from becoming permanent on the drive in the first place.

Comment: @Joel: Wrong. http://www.faronics.com/en/Products/DeepFreeze/DeepFreezeEducation.aspx

Comment: @Hello71 - _Nothing_ in there says it restores from an image. Faronics won't admit how they do it (http://www.faronics.com/en/support/FAQ.aspx#1), but it's fairly common knowledge among it's users that they install their own low-level disk drivers and redirect all changes you make to unused portions of the hard disk. When you reboot, these changes just don't exist any more. If you have access to a deepfreeze installation (I do) you can easily see the new disk drivers.

Comment: @Hello71 - this difference is important, because it means that unlike other products DeepFreeze requires only about 5Mb of disk space, takes very little time to install (you don't have to build/compress a gigabytes of data into an image), and you can easily and relatively quickly update your frozen machine by "thawing" it for update periods.

Comment: @Hello71 also see the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_(software)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to the bios and setting your system clock ahead 60 days. That should force the machine into a thawed state (trial or not).

Answer (score 1):

There is some information [here](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-95/deep-freeze-password-recovery/142199.html) but I kinda doubt that will help unless you are using the trial version.

If you are feeling adventurous, you can try this process which I just made up (but probably won't work):

1. Do a full backup with something like [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/) or [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) and save to an external drive
2. Boot a live CD like [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.org/)
3. From Knoppix, navigate over to where deep freeze is installed in windows
4. Delete or move everything related to deep freeze so that it is unable to start with windows
5. Restart and see what happened to windows (maybe even try safe mode)

If this totally messed up your computer, restore from backup.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download ADF Anti DeepFreeze
2. Extract the .rar file
3. Open ADF7 if you have version 7 and ADF for Df version6 below

   1. Then set it to start new

Answer (score -1):

Use This tutorial:

http://www.4shared.com/zip/Pu0gfeDWba/DF_Manual_Hck1n9_Final.html

Password: Mani_fa

In summary:

1. You need 2 software : WinPE (or any windows live) and HexEditor
2. Boot Your PC via Win Live
3. Open Hex Editor in Win live and Edit "Persi0.sys" file which is in below path
   WinDrive:\Persi0.sys
4. You must change one or two hex code to disable the password which is shown in tutorial.Offset no 184 from "7D" will change to "00"....Remember offset no 184 must be "7D", If it is not your Deep Freeze version not supported.
5. After rebooting computer with main OS, You are able to uninstall the program because Deep freeze will be in unfrozen mode.
6. This method only works for Deep freeze version 7 and higher, for earlier versions you can use ADF 0.1 up to ADF 0.5
7. This Method discovered personally ,You can publish and use this method but Do not remove main author name and his email and remember to refer the reference link.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because links die, leaving a meaningless post. Please summarize the method in your answer.