# Disable Deep Freeze

Tags: windows, deep-freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninstall Deep Freeze manually using the Windows registry](https://superuser.com/questions/147180/uninstall-deep-freeze-manually-using-the-windows-registry)

Is there a way to forcefully remove Deep Freeze from a computer without knowing the password and without having to boot to another environment?

Comment: No, since that is the point of Deep Freeze.

Comment: @RandolphWest: it must be theoretically possible, provided you have admin access to the frozen computer - Deep Freeze doesn't include a hypervisor layer, does it?  So software could in principle bypass the Deep Freeze redirection layer and write changes directly to the underlying disk.  The most practical approach would probably be to feed access to the underlying disk to a WinPE VM so you don't need to handle NTFS and raw registry files.  However, unless someone has already built a turnkey solution, this is unlikely to be feasible for the OP.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Theoretically possible, given physical access to the machine? Sure. However, unlikely.