# Deleted Deep Freeze installation folder but Deep Freeze is still active

Tags: windows-8, uninstall, deep-freeze

[Faronics Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/enterprise/) was installed in my computer, I wanted to get rid of it so I thawed the PC for some reboots—5 or 6 I don't remember—then rebooted and **big mistake**: I deleted the installation folder instead of ***uninstalling*** it first.

I thought it was all good, I had forgotten about it already and just now when I rebooted last time—it’s been like two days since—I see Deep Freeze actions taking place again.

I don’t understand, in the task manager the service `DFServ` shows Stopped but if I go to “CompMgmt -> Services -> DFserv” shows a Disabled status. Registry entries are still there too.

Since I don’t have the installation folder I cannot uninstall it and still as there is nothing there I don't get how in the world the program is still doing it’s job?

If I try to run the installer an error shows saying:

> Deep Freeze Standard must be disabled before any Install/Uninstall can
>   proceed.

`C:` is the frozen drive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand one thing 1st is that, there is no uninstall for Deepfreeze. if you wanna get rid of that, you have to run it again and that instance will ask you if you wanna Remove it permanently.(so you won't uninstall it from windows uninstaller)

**Solution:**

If the Deep Freeze still runs. you have to make it thawed 1st by holding CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F6. then provide password if you gave it to it. then disable it and try installing it again.

**Updated:**
**or try this**

First have another unit to install Deep Freeze and do not put any password. Then, boot thaw that unit. Copy the file at the root, c:\ "Persi0.*" (something like this). Paste it to the root of the drive that you want to unfreeze, voilà! That machine will be unfreezed. You can now uninstall Deep Freeze after booting.

[Origin Post](https://superuser.com/questions/147180/uninstall-deep-freeze-manually-using-the-windows-registry)

Comment: That's the problem, it's NOT running, or at least there's no process, no indication at all of the program running and how could there be if I deleted the installation folder in which the path to executable was: C:\Program Files (x86)\Faronics\Deep Freeze\Install\C-0\DFServ.exe.
But somehow it waited for the 5 or 6 thawed reboots I mentioned earlier and now it's back on business freezing C: again.
Main problem: I don't have installation folder so I can't uninstall it, is there any other approach to fix this that doesn't need uninstalling the program to make it stop working???

Comment: Do you have the installation file with you? just like installing again, Run it. that will show you uninstalling option

Comment: No, it won´t. When I run it, it displays the error message I wrote earlier: "Deep Freeze Standard must be disabled before any Install/Uninstall can proceed"

Comment: I have no idea now but, Any SafeMode tries? did you try that?

Comment: check my updated post

Comment: I read your update, what do you mean by unit, do you mean another drive? cause as I told you the installer won´t run at all, not from any drive, it displays the error msg I told you. I think all I can do left now before having to reinstall the OS is to install the program in another laptop and copy the installation folder to this one and try to run it so I can uninstall it, anyway I hope it works, I really appreciate the help, I´ll let you know if it works, however any more ideas are most welcome.

Comment: yes, maybe another PC, however you need that installation foler and files

Comment: Oh, about that file Persi0.sys, yeah, I might have deleted it too, looks like I deleted all my options away,ggg.

Comment: that's right, won't I get those if I install it in another pc, including the Persi0.sys file??

Comment: you just copy all files from new installation folder and try